# Can I use expo packages in react native cli?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, package, expo

> Can I use expo packages in react native cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can read the full article here:
https://blog.expo.dev/you-can-now-use-expo-apis-in-any-react-native-app-7c3a93041331